# What are the motivating use-cases for each of Linux's SCHED_* scheduling algorithms?

Tags: c, linux, scheduling

I've been reading about Linux's various `SCHED_*` scheduling algorithms (which can be specified for a given thread/process via a call to [sched_setscheduler()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html)), and there is a good amount of information about how they work, but I haven't been able to find much about why each of them was created.

For example there is [SCHED_DEADLINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCHED_DEADLINE), but it's not very clear under what circumstances it would be appropriate/beneficial to use it rather than one of the other algorithms.

Therefore, my question is:  for each of these algorithms, what is a "canonical" example of an application for which that algorithm would be the preferred/most-appropriate one to use?  i.e. what specific motivating use-cases did the designers of the algorithm have in mind when they created the algorithm?

For reference, I've listed the algorithms below, along with my current (partial) understanding of what they should be used for.

- `SCHED_OTHER` -- for all "normal" (non-time-sensitive) applications that need to share the CPU as fairly as possible, with generally-good response time and no chance of thread-starvation, regardless of how the threads behave.  For example, a web browser would use this scheduler.
- `SCHED_FIFO` -- for time-sensitive (soft-real-time) applications that need low latency at all times if at all possible, even if it means lower-priority threads might starve in certain scenarios.  For example, an audio driver might use this scheduler.
- `SCHED_RR` -- ???
- `SCHED_BATCH` -- for applications that don't care about timing/latency at all, but just need as many spare cycles as the system can afford when it's not doing anything else.  For example, a bitcoin mining program might use this scheduler.
- `SCHED_ISO` -- ???
- `SCHED_IDLE` -- ???
- `SCHED_DEADLINE` -- ???

Comment: Why would the developers need to have such a use case in mind? The Unix/Linux philosophy is to provide the widest range and allow users to choose what best suits their needs.

Comment: When was the last time you wrote software with no use-case in mind?  How did you know what to write?

Comment: I have never in my career used a bezier curve nor do I know what they are for, yet I have ported graphics libraries that implement them.

Comment: Cool -- I bet the guy who wrote the graphics library knew what a bezier curve was for, and had an idea about how people were likely to want to use the bezier curve functions of his library; otherwise he wouldn't have had any reason to include that functionality in the library.

Comment: Well, Bezier developed it for car design, but I think it has many uses.  I don't know why I would use it vs B-spline or cubic spline, tho.  They all have similar capabilities, and they are all provided by some graphics libraries.  For scheduling, I'd be unsurprised if there was a paper on scheduling written in the 1960's and somebody just implemented all of the suggested algorithms without knowing about specific use cases.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the Linux kernel maintainers would allow code to be merged into the mainline kernel distribution without understanding why that code would be useful.

Comment: In my opinion the question is way too broad to provide an answer less than a few books. Anyway, for "_... `SCHED_DEADLINE`, but it's not very clear under what circumstances it would be appropriate/beneficial to use it rather than one of the other algorithms._", does [Deadline Task Scheduling](https://docs.kernel.org/scheduler/sched-deadline.html) answer your question?

Comment: I provided answers for three of them that were just a couple of sentences, so I think it's possible to do the same for the others.  In any case, thank you for the link, I see it contained this:  "There are no limitations on what kind of task can exploit this new scheduling discipline, even if it must be said that it is particularly suited for periodic or sporadic real-time tasks that need guarantees on their timing behavior, e.g., multimedia, streaming, control applications, etc."